# Why isn't iframe designed to be able to load only a certain element of another website?

Tags: html, url

Reading the answers in [iframe to Only Show a Certain Part of the Page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3272071/3416774), and given the fact that you can always hide and customize elements via the devtool, I have a hypothesis that the web (in general sense, not any particular web page) is not designed to be able to load a certain element of a website with an URL. Is that correct? Why is it not a built-in feature of URL?

Comment: Sometimes other websites are willing to publish smaller pieces of their site as stand-alone components.  Is the other site not willing to do that in this case?

Comment: I mean, you can always hide the element you don't want to via the devtool. I wonder why this is not a built-in feature of URL?

Comment: Built-in feature of HTML maybe, more that URL. "I mean, you can always hide the element you don't want to via the devtool." That is unclear. The web moved out of SGML/XHTML and rigid structures, and leans more towards mix and match. If you need specific things, then there is typically an API which gives richer control. Do remember also that lots of content authors do not want to be "included" in other pages, specifically since in your example, if there is for example a "copyright" mention what you want to do would allow to remove it.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Can you give some examples of the mix and match structures? If I need an overview of these structures (including the rigid ones), where should I start?

Comment: Most browsers won't have problems parsing `<div><p></div>` which is invalid XML/XHTML. Which is also why you can't parse current HTML with just a regexp.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek ah, so you meant that it is now flexible to read invalid XML/XHTML, rather than meant that the web is no longer use XML anymore?

Comment: The web does not use XHTML (Based of XML) indeed, since long ago. HTML remains a broken descendant of it.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek what is it using now? API?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is unclear.

When you are loading an iframe (you should avoid doing this to the extent possible) you are embedding a site which is likely not in your control [ because if it were you should not use an iframe ] - were you able to specify certain parts this would break your website if those parts were to go away.

In fact, I would argue you CAN specify only to load part of a page to the extent that the remote website enables this functionality.  You can append parameters onto your request which can be used by the site in the iframe to customise itself - and this is standard practice.  The point being though that the other site needs to support this functionality.

If you are wanting to only embed part of the site you should be using AJAX and/or some API functionality to query the remote site and embed the contents in yours.   If you can't do this you need to ask why not - and often the answer will be because the author of that site does not want you to be able to do that.

With respect of your hypothesis "I have a hypothesis that the web is not designed to be able to load a certain element of a website with an URL. Is that correct?" - that is correct in the general case, although it is easy enough to extend the sites to add that functionality.

Comment: What if I'm certain that hiding or removing other elements won't affect the one I want to iframe. Or in other words, why doesn't the iframe tag provide some attributes that are equivalent with the devtool?

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about with a devtool, but the simple fact is that an iframe is not designed to work the way you wish it did.  If you need that functionality you should be using an API.  (Its worth remembering that iframes are > 20 year old technology - when the Internet was a very different place and web standards were way, way simpler).  If todays browsers were written from scratch the iframe would not exist.  It stands to reason that if the entities guiding the web are trying to phase it out, they are not going to add more support for it.

Comment: hmm, let's say that I load Stack Exchange, then I use the devtool to hide everything except this answer. The answer will be still there, unbroken. And I guess Stack Exchange uses recent technology, not 20 year old one. So if I use iframe (which in my impression is just a very basic browser), then in theory it can have an attribute to hide the elements I don't want to see. I get that no one supports it now, but when it was popular, why didn't W3C design it to reach its full potential?

Comment: An iframe is not a basic browser. Its a mechanism to view another page imbedded in your current page. I'm fairly sure it predates w3. Reading https://www.w3.org/html/wg/spec/the-iframe-element.html they see it (correctly) as the iframe being a single element, not an include - and if you look at the screed of warnings it jumps out that the technology is dangerous enough not to encourage its use/obfusication with modifiers of the content in the iframe.

Comment: Further, I think you can modify the contents if an iframe by parsing it in Javascript.

Comment: I open a new following question. Hope to see you there: [If iframe is so outdated, why do large websites still provide it to users?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/140383/52079)